# MySQL auto increment ID based on the values of two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to auto increment the `id` field of my database based on the values of two other columns in the inserted row?

I'd like to set up my database so that when multiple rows are inserted at the same time, they keep their `tracknumber` ordering. The ID field should auto increment based firstly on the automatically generated `timestamp` field, and then secondly the `tracknumber` contained within that timestamp.

Here's an example of how the database might look:

```
id |  tracknumber | timestamp
________________________________________

1  | 1            | 2014-03-31 11:35:17
2  | 2            | 2014-03-31 11:35:17
3  | 3            | 2014-03-31 11:35:17
4  | 1            | 2014-04-01 09:10:14
5  | 2            | 2014-04-01 09:10:14
```

I've been reading up on triggers but not sure if that's appropriate here? I feel as though i'm missing an obvious function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting them in one transaction and or script, then sort the data yourself in the server side according to these two fields (assuming you create timestamp on server side too because that would seem logical) and then insert the rows one after another. I don't think it is necessary to overthink this and look for a difficult approach in the database. Database will still be inserting rows one after another, not all at once so there is no way it will know that it needs to do some kind of sorting beforehand. It is you who has to do it.

Comment: Useful - was definitely overthinking it. Using ORDER BY on multiple columns now to achieve the correct sorting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

There is no *automatic* way to do this.  You can do it with triggers, if you like.  Note the plural, you will need triggers for `insert`, `update`, and `delete`, if you want the numbering to remain accurate as the data changes.

You can do this one the query side, if the goal is to enumerate the values.  Here is one method using a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from table t2 where t2.timestamp = t.timestamp and t2.id <= t.id
       ) as tracknumber
from table t;
```

The performance of this might even be reasonable with an index on `table(timestamp, id)`.

If the data is being created once, you can also populate the values using an `update` query.